# Proposal: Start some FAQ/category tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Stack Overflow employs a brilliant tool:  FAQ tags.  Questions that fall uner a certain category, like common questions about C++, are tagged [c++-faq](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq).  I think a variation on this would be an excellent resource here.

---

For instance, our assortment of questions about how lightsabers work, including the following:

[What keeps a lightsaber from going on infinitely?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/what-keeps-a-lightsaber-from-going-on-infinitely)

[Why does a lightsaber turn off when a Jedi dies or drops it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/why-do-lightsabers-turn-off-when-a-jedi-dies-or-drops-it)

[What keeps lightsabers from going through each other?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21465/what-keeps-lightsabers-from-going-through-each-other)

[Which button activates Skywalker's lightsaber, and why is it inconsistent?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113358/which-button-activates-skywalkers-lightsaber)

[What are all the known lightsaber designs?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111585/what-are-all-the-known-lightsaber-designs)

[Does construction of a Lightsaber require use of the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26843/does-construction-of-a-lightsaber-require-use-of-the-force)

[Any good resources about lightsaber production?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114698/any-good-resources-about-lightsaber-production/114700#114700)

[What goes into the design of lightsaber hilts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7283/what-goes-into-the-design-of-lightsaber-hilts)

Could be tagged [lightsaber-design-faq](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightsaber-design-faq) or something.

---

We could also have a tag - say, [lightsaber-ownership-faq](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightsaber-ownership-faq) for all the questions about what happened to specific lightsabers:

[In Star Wars: "The Force Awakens," how could this lightsaber have turned up where it did?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111121/in-star-wars-the-force-awakens-how-could-this-item-have-turned-up-in-this-lo)

[Did Luke retrieve his Lightsaber from second Death Star?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72875/did-luke-retrieve-his-lightsaber-from-second-death-star)

[What color is Luke’s lightsaber blade?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113119/what-color-is-luke-s-lightsaber-blade)

[Where are Obi-Wan Kenobi's and Qui-gon Jinn's Lightsabers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75852/where-are-obi-wan-kenobis-and-qui-gon-jinns-lightsabers)

---

And the slew of questions that follow the formula "Why didn't they do [insert idea here] with the One Ring?" could be tagged [one-ring-faq](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-ring-faq):

[Why not let a dwarf carry the One Ring to Mount Doom, since their will cannot be dominated by the rings of power?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68280/why-not-let-a-dwarf-carry-the-one-ring-to-mount-doom-since-their-will-cannot-be)

[Why not encase the One Ring in solid metal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114649/why-not-encase-the-one-ring-in-solid-metal)

[Why didn’t they just take the ring to Valinor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64471/why-didn-t-they-just-take-the-ring-to-valinor)

[Why didn't Elrond or Círdan take the ring from Isildur by force and destroy it?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38417/why-didnt-elrond-or-c%c3%adrdan-take-the-ring-from-isildur-by-force-and-destroy-it)

[Why not use the Ring?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91658/why-not-use-the-ring)

[Why didn't Gandalf or Frodo Fly to Mount Doom?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2333/why-didnt-gandalf-or-frodo-fly-to-mount-doom?s=1|0.2325)

---

Other potential FAQ/category tag subjects:

- Who is/isn't a horcrux questions
- Sorting Hat questions
- Borg questions
- Tolkien Elves questions
- Force Powers questions
- Has comic book character X fought comic book character Y questions
- Etc.

---

You get the idea.

As our friend Mike Edenfield [says](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27009001#27009001):

> Once we have it we have an easy way to decide which one is the 'canonically best' duplicate to use

And I think it would bring many more advantages as well - ease of researching a specific idea, more intelligent categorization (a person or group of people might be tasked with deciding which questions make the cut for the FAQ tags, which is more reliable than trusting every user who happens by to use the right tag for the right reasons), etc.

---

### The issue isn't whether the specific tags I've suggested make sense, but rather, is the idea in general a good one?  Should we try to work out how to adopt this kind of tagging system?  What would the pros and cons be?

## WHAT SAY YOU?

*Note:  Feel free to edit this question and add ideas if you like.*

Comment: Oh lord, more tags, each more taggy than the last.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield - Yar.  It would be FAS (frequently asked subject) rather than FAQ.

Comment: Since I can't be bothered to gather evidence or write up a thorough argument, I'll just dump my opinion down here: This is a good idea if we have a *lot* of frequently asked questions, a.k.a. frequent dupe targets. Otherwise, there's no difference between [tag:lightsaber-faq] and [tag:lightsaber] and we may as well stick to the latter.

Comment: I'm confused by @MikeEdenfield's comment (quoted in the question). How would having these tags make it easier to choose canonical questions, when the point of these tags is to *identify* canonical questions? To put that another way: once we've identified a canonical question, what benefit is served by tagging it?

Comment: SO's FAQ tags narrow down a *very* broad subject (like C++) into a list of canonical questions in order to make it easier for users to find the canonical question. Only the broadest tags here (e.g. Harry Potter, Star Wars) are potentially good candidates for getting their own FAQ tag (certainly not a narrow subject like lightsabers). Even then, in my experience I don't have much trouble finding those canonical questions (in, say, Star Wars) either before I ask my own question or for closing a dupe. I see no benefit to this and disagree with this proposal.

Comment: is there a report of "most duplicated questions" ? If so that would indicate the need for extra tag functionality and could even be used as a basis to automate it (ie new users on sign up could see a "list of the top 20 most often asked questions in the last year")

Comment: [There is](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightsaber?sort=frequent), @JohnMcNamara. This counts any link, not just those from duplicates - but in practice, it usually works well enough.

Comment: @Shog9  Thanks, I assumed that was per tag only but [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172726/whats-the-frequent-sort-function) seems to indicate otherwise. Is it possible to get a count of the number of duplicates for a given question, as a non-mod ?

Comment: oh links, not dups, nevermind.

Comment: To answer that question, [you can write a query](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/what-is-the-most-rampant-duplicate-on-stack-exchange-sites/168289#168289) @John

Answer (score 11):

Stack Overflow has a few FAQ tags because traditionally it was extremely difficult for people to *find* the questions they needed in a timely manner.

For example, the C++ tag on Stack Overflow gets, on average, somewhere north of 200 questions per day. And a lot of them are duplicates, but *finding* the questions they duplicate is tedious, especially in the past when the UI didn't offer a list of suggestions and there was no [list of frequently-linked questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightsaber?sort=frequent).

Y'all don't get 200 questions about lightsabers every day. In fact, there haven't been 200 questions about lightsabers *ever* asked here. The entire list of questions about lightsabers is shorter than the list of *frequently asked C++ questions* on Stack Overflow. I strongly suspect you'd put more work into creating these lists than you would ever save by *having* them.

But you don't have to create them. [The system handily builds them for you.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightsaber?sort=frequent) So just use what you get for free...

#### Related: [Special handling for FAQ questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168359/special-handling-for-faq-questions)

Comment: The problem with tags applied by everyone and his brother is that they are often misapplied, and cover a wide array of subjects - how do lightsabers work?  Why did Anakin use 2 lightsabers one time?  Who uses lightsabers?  What do colors mean?  Can a lightsaber do this?  Who is the stormtrooper with a lightsaber-proof stick?

Comment: I'm suggesting that a couple of people would be allowed to use their judgment to put subcategory tags for common types of questions, and that only these people should apply these special tags.

Comment: Yeah, see the MSE question I linked. Also, any tagging solution based on having only "the right sort of people" involved is pretty much doomed. We have a reputation system, and it even grants [extra weight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) to folks who've demonstrated expertise; if that isn't good enough, if folks with *actual knowledge* have to be disenfranchised to achieve some ideal organizational scheme... Then there are much more fundamental issues at work.

Comment: The frequently linked questions list is some help, but the list of suggested duplicates is seriously broken:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232242/help-us-find-duplicates-efficiently