# How can I get a report of most duplicated questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

How can I get a report of most duplicated questions ?
Inspired by recent discussions and curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Shog9 's [comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8003/proposal-start-some-faq-category-tags#comment22553_8003) I had a go at using data.stackexchange.com to get the data. His example seems to be a bit out of date as regards the schema so I researched a new working version.

I'm not yet fully familiar with the full db schema so feel free to improve it.

Bear in mind this only lists actually declared duplicate questions, not tags or groups of "very similar but not duplicate" questions.

This only lists question with 3+ dups, there are a few 100 2 dups.

[For main site](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/426939/questions-with-3-or-more-identified-duplicates)

[and for meta!](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.scifi/query/426939/questions-with-3-or-more-identified-duplicates)